# Inheritance from deprecated class

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning, c++98, deprecation-warning

I would like mark a class as deprecated using C++98 and the g++ compiler in order to receive a warning when this class is used directly, or when someone derives from this class.

Apparently, using `__attribute__ ((__deprecated__))` works when the class is used, but not for inheritance.

For example:

```cpp
#if defined(__GNUC__)
# define DEPRECATED __attribute__ ((__deprecated__))
#else
# define DEPRECATED
#endif


class DEPRECATED Foo
{
public:
    explicit Foo(int foo) : m_foo(foo) {}
    virtual ~Foo() {}

    virtual int get() { return m_foo; }

private:
    int m_foo;
};


class Bar : public Foo // This declaration does not produce a compiler
                       // warning.
{
public:
    explicit Bar(int bar) : Foo(bar), m_bar(bar) {}
    virtual ~Bar() {}

    virtual int get() { return m_bar; }

private:
    int m_bar;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo f(0); // This declaration produces a warning.
    Bar b(0); // This declaration does not produce a warning.
    return b.get();
}
```

I would expect to receive a warning from "class Bar : public Foo", but this is not the case (tested with g++ 5.2.1).

Is there a way to have a warning when deriving from a deprecated class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way I can think to work around this is, instead of actually marking that class deprecated, make a private class of that class which is marked deprecated, and which it instantiates as a temporary variable in its constructor. So you will still get the deprecation warning if you instantiate a derived class.

```
class base {
  class DEPRECATED deprecator {};
public:
  base() {
    deprecator issue_warning;
    (void) issue_warning; // this line is no-op to silence unused variable warning for local variable
  }
};

class derived : public base {
public:
  derived()
    : base()
  {
    // I am also deprecated, because I called the ctor for base
    // which instantiates a deprecated class
  }
};
```

This may be more complicated to implement if `base` has many different constructors, but this at least gives the idea. In general whenever an instance of `derived` is constructed, an instance of `base` must be constructed -- one of the base ctors must run to completion before the lifetime of the `derived` instance can begin.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this, but if the object is instantiated in the constructor of the base class, I will receive a warning when building the base class, but not when building or instantiating the derived one... or perhaps I didn't understand what you mean... Can you improve your answer with an example, please?

Comment: Well, you could add `base::deprecator` as member of `base` and then you dont need to worry about contructors